# PHP Code stopping at > and not ?>

Tags: server, php

I'm using Ubuntu server 16 and have installed php and when I have a php file, the code breaks at the > and shows the rest of the code on a webpage.

- I got the code from this site: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo
- My server is using Mariadb

Is something wrong with the code or my server?
Thanks

Comment: Could not use more than two links https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfXSI.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMI33.png

Comment: Have you checked the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102368/php-treating-greater-than-as-end-script)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was evidently that the file was not using a `.php` file extension. While Unix-like systems typically don't care what the file extension is (i.e. programs should be able to tell filetype without the extension in most cases), the web server does rely on the file extension to tell it whether or not it needs to do preprocessing.

The solution, of course, is to use a `.php` extension for the file rather than some other extension.

As a suggestion for troubleshooting in the future, the linked image from the text editor shows based on its coloring that it, in fact, believes *something* stops at the `>` character in the `if` statement. While it is easy to identify this as the result of a wrong file extension in retrospect, it could have been a clue that the issue did not lie in an error in the web server.

Credit for the solution goes almost exclusively to [md5madman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133504/md5madman) on for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102407/6192153) to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102368/php-treating-greater-than-as-end-script).